# How do I get the photo URL when reading a user's posts and they Like a photo?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, photo, posts

I'm reading my user's friend's wall posts with the Graph API "/637674567/posts".  One of the data items is that he likes a photo.  Is there a way to get a URL for the photo?  When I get the information about the item, I get the following (below).  I've verified that Darryl allows apps to see his photos and status updates.  I've tried getting every permission available for my app.  I can't figure it out.  Any help?  Thanks!

```
{
  "id": "637674567_10151119619094448",   
  "from": {    
    "name": "Darryl Green",     
    "id": "637674567"  
  },   
  "story": "Darryl Green likes a photo.",   
  "story_tags": {    
    "0": [      
      {        
        "id": 637674567,         
        "name": "Darryl Green",         
        "offset": 0,         
        "length": 19,         
        "type": "user"      
      }    
    ]  
  },   
  "type": "status",   
  "application": {    
    "name": "Likes",     
    "id": "2409997254"  
  },   
  "created_time": "2012-08-29T03:29:03+0000",   
  "updated_time": "2012-08-29T03:29:03+0000",   
  "comments": {    
    "count": 0  
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with statuses. I opened a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/522743067756848).

Answer (score 0):

Your friend might have enabled apps to access his photos. But there is another level of privacy setting, that is what kind of data can the apps his friend (you) use, be able to access from his feed ?
Chances are, if those settings don't allow for access to his photos when you are trying to access them via your app, you won't be able to do so.
For a more detailed explanation, please check this reply - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/12151338/1628782.

Comment: I checked that and he had the "My Photos", "My Status Updates" and "My Links" checked.  So that's not it.

Comment: What are the privacy settings on the photo that was liked ? Are they from a different profile ?

Comment: I'm not sure on that user's privacy setting, so I used my profile instead ("/me/posts") and I get the same results.  I varified that apps have access to all my data and I requested every single permission I could for the Graph API Explorer.  How do I get to the photo?